# My program requires java JDK to run?

Tags: java

this is a kind of weird non programming (but java related) question.

I created a java program (game) using just normal java, and no libraries.

In ordor to double click/open it, you need to have java SDK/JDK (I don't know which) installed.

I tested this multiple times, and in order for my PC and Mac to launch it, you need to install it.

is there anyway to get around this? I know Minecraft doesn't force you to download the JDK.

Here's the link to source code of my game if your interested (no, it is not a virus): http://www.filedropper.com/daplatform

Thanks, Jake

Here's the link to the download of the JDK (Its next to the giant Netbeans download): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: BackSlash I added it.

Comment: It justs needs the java runtime engine, JRE. Search oracle java.

Comment: Im asking how can I create the program and have it run without someone downloading an external program?

Comment: @user3131055 You can't. Java **requires** the runtime environment to run. So if you don't have the JRE installed java won't run. If you don't want your program to require an external application to run, then use C/C++ and compile your application natively

Comment: Actually he can, no need to be so negative on the poor guy.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can wrap both your program and the JRE required to run it into a single executable for the target platform.

For example your windows installer would include both a windows JRE and your program itself.

Launch4j http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/ lets you wrap a Java program into a windows executable and gives you options about how to handle the JRE, including bundling it.